# Using sql join returns data but not the other query

Tags: oracle, join

Write a query in SQL to display the name of the country, city, and the departments which are running there. As I was writing query for the question above using HR schema (diagram available [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e10831/diagrams.htm#CIHGFFHI)) . 1st query did not return any result

```
1st Query:
select country_name,city, department_name 
from HR.COUNTRIES c, HR.Locations l, HR.DEpartments d
where c.COUNTRY_ID = l.country_id
and d.DEPARTMENT_ID=l.location_id;
```

2nd query did return result.

```
select country_name,city,department_name 
from HR.COUNTRIES c join HR.LOCATIONS l on c.COUNTRY_ID =l.country_id
join HR.DEPARTMENTS d on l.location_id=d.location_id;
```

Why did the 1st query not work? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You last condition is wrong. A `department` has a `location_id` you should use to join on `location`:

```
SELECY country_name, city, department_name 
FROM   hr.countries c, hr.Locations l, hr.departments d
WHERE  c.country_id = l.country_id AND
       d.location_id = l.location_id;
-- Here--^
```

Note, by the way, that implicit joins (having multiple tables in the `from` clause) is a bit outdated, and it's recommended you use explicit `join` clauses:

```
SELECY country_name, city, department_name 
FROM   hr.countries c
JOIN   hr.Locations l ON c.country_id = l.country_id 
JOIN   hr.departments d ON d.location_id = l.location_id;
```

Comment: Copy paste at it's best..Thanks for the tips on explicit join.